# Replace a Tag in a XML File Unix

Tags: xml, unix, xhtml

I have a normal xml File where I need to replace a tag with another.
The tag I have is  there is no content between  and any other tags. Now i need to change  into 
I've tried using sed -e 's/application/new_application/g' but the output were: ""

Is there a simple way to change  by using the command line?

Comment: what is you command?

Comment: "sed -e 's/application/new_application/g' FILENAME"

Comment: seemed nothing wrong, check your input file?

Comment: Yes, simple xml File full of Tags. Nothing seems to be wrong there. Is it maybe because you can't use sed to change a tag in a xml file?

Comment: why not? xml files are just plain text files with some syntax, `sed` does not see the difference

Comment: I converted the file into a none XML File and than changed the tag with sed. It worked.